# QGIS "Statistics by Categories" tool greyed out at 3.8.3

Tags: qgis, statistics

I have both 2.18.28 and 3.8.3 loaded on my computer.  I have a Geopackage containing a line layer of hiking trails.  The attribute table contains two fields:

1. surface_type (text)
2. length_miles (decimal)

I am trying to sum length_miles by surface_type, using the **Statistics by Categories** tool.

Using 2.18.28 the tool works perfectly.

However, at 3.8.3 the *Field(s) with categories* option is greyed out (please see highlighted screenshot).  This is where I would normally select the surface_type field.  Now that it is greyed out I cannot calculate miles by surface_type.

The Help section offers no clue.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you click the `...` button next to "field(s) with categories"?

Comment: Well, I'll be darned!  Clicking the ... button worked.  It looked greyed out, so I never bothered to click it.  Silly me.  If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I'll thankfully credit you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the `...` button next to "Field(s" with categories". This should open a multi-select window where you can choose one or more fields.

[image]